# Make perl regex search exit with failure if not found

Tags: macos, grep, perl, terminal.app

With `grep` I get a failure return code/exit status if no result is found.

How can I do the same thing with perl?

Basically, I would like to change the following so that it exits with status 1 if no match is found.

```
echo foo | perl -nle'print if m{bar}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If i was to solve the problem "quick & dirty" I would simply try something like this

> echo foo | perl -nle' print if m{bar} or print 1'

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: That prints "1", but doesn't exit with status 1/failure.

Comment: you can replace print 1 with `die 1` (for failure; should abort script) or `exit 1` (return status of 1, but don't throw error) if you want. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html

Comment: Hi. Like Frank said, die or exit will return 1 or failure.

Comment: @EamonnTravers Thank you very much for this alternative! It working awesomely.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
echo foo | perl -nlE'print if $t ||= m{bar} }{ exit 1 if !$t'
```

Explanation:

The "Eskimo kiss"™ `}{`  closes the  `while` loop (which is implied by `-n`). In the `if` statement a varibable `$t` is `1` as soon as the first match happens.